# SQL RegExp to pull the slug from a URL

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I want to pull the slug from a URL using SQL regular expressions

https://example.com/december-2019/content/**this-is-the-slug/**

I eventually came across this

```
SELECT
regexp_extract(url, r'\/([a-z0-9_-]*[\/]?)$') slug
FROM table
```

This gives me 
**this-is-the-slug/**

However, I just want **this-is-the-slug**

I know I can just nest my query and remove the end '/', but is there anything I can add to the RegExp `'\/([a-z0-9_-]*[\/]?)$'` above that will do it all in one?

Also, how does the RegExp work? I'm a bit confused about how it operates. 
Is it something like this

`$` # start at end of string 
`/(  )` # work back and find the first '/' and create a capturing group () 
`[ ]*` # create a character set [] in the capturing group and match all elements in it using * 
`a-z0-9_-` # match all these characters in the character set and pull them out. 
`[\/]?` # something to do with greedy matching? Not sure what this does.

Any help on this would be great. Thanks

Comment: Move `/?` outside of group: `r'/([a-z0-9_-]*)/?$'`

Comment: I highly recommend the website https://regexr.com/ - you can troubleshoot your regex there, try and out changes live, and it also explains what each character is doing.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  `r'/([a-z0-9_-]*)/?$'` this works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a non regex option using the `SPLIT()` function:

```
SELECT ARRAY_REVERSE(SPLIT(RTRIM(url, '/'), '/'))[SAFE_OFFSET(0)]
FROM yourTable;
```

This approach removes the trailing path separator `/`, then splits the URL on `/` to generate an array.  Note that we use `RTRIM` for this purpose.  This means that the URL input won't be affected if it doesn't have a trailing path separator.  The last entry in that array is retained, which should be the slug.

Comment: Great, this works as well. So the url is split on the '/', then we reverse the order with `array_reverse` and select the 0 element?

Answer (score 0):

I would still recommend using REGEXP in cases like yours - your regular expression was very close to what it should of be - you just need to move `/?` outside of captured group like in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'https://example.com/december-2019/content/this-is-the-slug1/' url UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://example.com/december-2019/content/this-is-the-slug2' 
)
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, r'\/([a-z0-9_-]*?)/?$') slug
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row slug     
1   this-is-the-slug1    
2   this-is-the-slug2
```